# How to show validation invalid form message in AMP?

Tags: forms, amp-html

I have a simple form in an AMP website in which I'm using the `as-you-go` strategy for field validation.

I would like to show a generic message next to the submit button saying that the form is still invalid.

```
  <form method="POST" class="p2" action-xhr=".../api/contacts" custom- 
      validation-reporting="as-you-go" target="_top">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email_input" name="email" 
       required>
     <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing" validation-for="email_input"></span>
     <input name="phone" id="phone_input" required>
     <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing"></span>

     //SHOW Invalid form message here!
     <input id="btn-form-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      <div id="submit-success" submit-success>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
           <h6>Success!</h6>
        </template>
      </div>
      <div submit-error>
          <template type="amp-mustache">
               <h6> Error</h6>
          </template>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I would like to know if its possible to show a generic error message next to the submit input saying that the form still invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CSS hooks provided by `amp-form`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#classes-and-css-hooks), specifically, `user-valid` and `user-invalid`.

```
      //SHOW Invalid form message here!
      <p class="message-when-invalid">One or more fields are invalid.</p>
      <input id="btn-form-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And in your CSS make sure that the message is hidden when the form is valid:

```
form.user-valid .message-when-invalid {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: This solution works but it has a problem, the message is displayed even if the user does not have interacted with the form.

Comment: You can make the message `hidden` by default and then use `amp-bind` to unhide it when any field is changed.

Comment: how can I do that with hidden? wich is a void attribute.

Comment: Using `[hidden]` with a boolean expression is valid (https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#bindings). Something like `[hidden]="myState.isModified"` with `on="change:AMP.setState({myState: { isModified: true } })"` on your inputs should work.